# How to change wallet in hardhat

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to make a simple governance protocol I was following along with a tutorial and I have working code.

In my hardhat config I add 2 private keys to the accounts tab:

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: INFURA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY_2],
      chainId: 80001,
    },
  },
//...
}
```

I have a deployment script which create a governance token:

```
const deployGovernanceToken: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  // @ts-ignore
  const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = hre
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const { deployer, user } = await getNamedAccounts()
  const governanceToken = await deploy("GovernanceToken", {
    from: deployer, args: [], log: true,
    waitConfirmations: networkConfig[network.name].blockConfirmations || 1,
  })
  await delegate(governanceToken.address, deployer, user)
  //...
}

const delegate = async (governanceTokenAddress: string, delegatedAccount: string, userAccount: string) => {
  const governanceToken = await ethers.getContractAt("GovernanceToken", governanceTokenAddress)
  const transactionResponse = await governanceToken.mint(userAccount, "10000000000000000000000000");
  await transactionResponse.wait(1)
  console.log(`Checkpoints: ${await governanceToken.numCheckpoints(delegatedAccount)}`)
}
```

Then I have a script which is meant to vote on a proposal.

```
export async function vote(proposalId: string, voteWay: number, reason: string) {
  console.log("Voting...")
  const signer = await ethers.getSigners()

  console.log('signers:' + signer);

  const governor = await ethers.getContract("GovernorContract")
  const voteTx = await governor.castVoteWithReason(proposalId, voteWay, reason)
  const voteTxReceipt = await voteTx.wait(1)
  console.log(voteTxReceipt.events[0].args.reason)
  const proposalState = await governor.state(proposalId)
  console.log(`Current Proposal State: ${proposalState}`)
  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    await moveBlocks(VOTING_PERIOD + 1)
  }
}
```

How can I change to use my named user when voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `.connect()`

```
Let accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
admin = accounts[0];
user1 = accounts[1];
user2 = accounts[2];
await governor.connect(user1).castVoteWithReason(proposalId, voteWay, reason);
```

Comment: Are the others users the same as the named accounts setup in hardhat?

Comment: wdym? could you elaborate

Comment: I think im a bit confused, I provided 2 private keys to the mumbai network, the second private key, how do I access the user from that private key?

Comment: First, you must add both private keys to the .env file which I believe you already did. second step is to load both of those private keys into the hardhat config file where you setuped Mumbai rpc. getSingers will use your private keys if you define your network when running the command. For suppose when you are running hardhat test you will write, npx hardhat test --network Mumbai. if you use --network localhost or don't define network it will use dummy key when you define network it will fetch private keys from .env

Comment: Okay so the first 2 accounts will link to the Private Keys and the rest are the existing dummies thanks!

Comment: Yes, but for suppose you got 5 accounts(you are using in script file) in total and you got 2 private keys set in total in the env and you try to deploy it to testnet it will through you error you. As you gotta define private key for every account you are using when running it on testnet/mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.connect()` method before calling your contract method.

To get other wallets you can use `ethers.getSigners()` which returns 3 wallets. The first one is the one that Hardhat uses by default.

```
const [owner, otherAccount] = await ethers.getSigners();

await governor.connect(otherAccount).castVoteWithReason(proposalId, voteWay, reason)
```

More information in the docs [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/test-contracts#using-a-different-address).